# ArrayList size 0 after deserialisation Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, deserialization

Hello I tried to make an app for displaying quote in Android Studio.
But I got stuck when reading.
I created an "ArrayList" with my custom class Quotes.
I seems to work ok when writing the ArrayList to the file, but when reading from it the size of ArrayList is 0.

```
public class SaveQuote extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextQuote;
EditText editTextAuthor;

Button btnSave;
ArrayList<Quote> arrQuo = new ArrayList<>();

public static ArrayList<Quote> arrayListQuotesSave;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_save_quote);
    init();
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String quote = editTextQuote.getText().toString();
            String author =editTextAuthor.getText().toString();
            addQuote(quote,author);
        }
    });

}

private void init(){
    editTextQuote = findViewById(R.id.editTextQuote);
    editTextAuthor = findViewById(R.id.editTextAuthor);

    btnSave = findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

    arrayListQuotesSave = new ArrayList<>();
}

private void addQuote(String quote, String author){

    Quote q = new Quote(quote, author);
    arrQuo.add(q);
    String path = this.getFilesDir().toString();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("Quotes.txt",MODE_APPEND);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(arrQuo);// when I write size  = 1
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("Quotes.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        arrQuo =(ArrayList<Quote>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you implement the Serializable interface for the Quote class ?

Comment: yep I do implement serializable

Answer (score 0):

I tried to passe a context and call the method openFileOutput on the context
so like this:

```
enter code here
FileOutputStream fs = context.openFileOutput("Quotes.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

enter code here

public class SaveQuote extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextQuote;
EditText editTextAuthor;

Button btnSave;
ArrayList<Quote> arrQuo = new ArrayList<>();

public static ArrayList<Quote> arrayListQuotesSave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_save_quote);
    init();
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String quote = editTextQuote.getText().toString();
            String author =editTextAuthor.getText().toString();
            if(quote.isEmpty() || author.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(SaveQuote.this,"Fill all fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                writeToFile(SaveQuote.this, quote, author);
                Toast.makeText(SaveQuote.this,"The quote was saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void init(){
    editTextQuote = findViewById(R.id.editTextQuote);
    editTextAuthor = findViewById(R.id.editTextAuthor);

    btnSave = findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

    arrayListQuotesSave = new ArrayList<>();
}
private void writeToFile(Context context,String quote,String author) {
    Quote q = new Quote(quote,author);
    MainActivity.arrayListQuotesMain.add(q);
    Integer size = MainActivity.arrayListQuotesMain.size();
    Log.v("Added","arrayListQuotesMain size is = "+size.toString());

    try {
        FileOutputStream fs = context.openFileOutput("Quotes.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
        oos.writeObject(MainActivity.arrayListQuotesMain);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }

    editTextQuote.setText("");
    editTextAuthor.setText("");
}

}
```